# How to store special characters in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I trying to save a string with special characters in oracle database. In this string contains all available characters in keyboard phone. The problem: some characters turned '¿'. I need to store the exact characters I inserted in.

I simulated some cases with the bellow code:

1 - I created a test table with some columns of different type, clob, nclob, varchar2, nvarchar2

```
create table specialCharacters (
  testColumn1 clob null,
  testColumn2 nclob null,
  testColumn3 varchar2(1000) null,
  testColumn4 nvarchar2(1000) null
);
```

2 - I wrote a example string with some special characters based on the keyboard fone:

' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔'

';,¿‽?`•~|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!'

3 - I inserted this strings in all columns in specialCharacters, I tried of two differents methods in clob and nclob:

```
insert into specialCharacters values 
  (' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔', 
   ' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔', 
   ' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔', 
   ' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔'
  );

insert into specialCharacters values 
  ( ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!',
   ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!',
   ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!',
   ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!'
  );
  
  
insert into specialCharacters values 
  (TO_CLOB(' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔'), 
   TO_NCLOB(' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔'), 
   ' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔', 
   ' ¹⅕⅙⅛¹½½⅓¼²⅔'
  );
  
insert into specialCharacters values 
  ( TO_CLOB(';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!'),
   TO_NCLOB(';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!'),
   ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!',
   ';,¿‽?`•~\|□{}€£¥₩♣︎♧¿◆◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《》¡¿,.#?$!%^@,?!!'
  );
```

4 - the select result in specialCharacters:

select * from specialCharacters;

[image]

**Edit**

NLS_CHARACTERSET:

[image]

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:

[image]

The function dump in clob columns doesn't appear to work, but in testColumn3 and testColumn4 returned this result:

[image]

[image]

Finally, I tried to change the character to AL32UTF8, but doesn't work, I think the pattern character already covers the AL32UTF8 character

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` of this database? And please provide an output of `select dump(testColumn1, 16) from specialCharacters` (reducing the sample string by characters that turn into question marks)

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7c240670b0e98e0922784e8fbaa94dfc). What are the character sets of your datebase?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Which client tool do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the charset on the database, recommended is AL32UTF8. If its different you may probably have to alter the character on your DB.
If its live/prod DB backup is advised.

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET');
```

[Refer this Oracle doc on charset](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG002)

Answer (score 0):

**Never** call `alter database character set ...`! You may corrupt your entire database.

Character set `WEMSWIN1252` cannot not store characters like `◇♥︎♡♠︎♤■□●○•°★☆▪︎¤《`. You need to use an Unicode character set, preferably UTF-8, aka. `AL32UTF8`. For proper migration see  (see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm) and/or [Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm))